# How to get the desired results for this scenario [SQL]

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to build a query for the following scenario :

Input table:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
-------------------------------
1       2       a       pi
1       4       a       ci
1       2       a       ci
2       3       a       pi
2       4       a       ci
1       3       a       ci
1       3       a       pi
```

Logic required:

Fetch all the records from the input table except for the records matching below condition.

If value of group (a,b) is same for multiple rows, then only keep the row that has d='pi'
Ex: for row  1 & 3 value of (a,b) = (1,2) we need to keep only row 1 that has d='pi'.

Final desired output:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4 
---------------------------------
1       2       a       pi
1       4       a       ci
2       3       a       pi
2       4       a       ci
1       3       a       pi
```

Please help me out.

Comment: And are there any constraints on the table?

Comment: Do we have to factor in the possibility of two rows with the the same a,b and d='pi'? And if so, what do you want returned?

Comment: Yes . In case of multiple records having same a,b we need to need to select only the ones having values of column D='PI'. Other than this no other condition is to be applied and all the records are to be selected . Am I clear? Any help would be great.

Comment: Then Gordon has nailed it for you.

Comment: @MichaelBroughton What's wrong with my solution? It's less contrived, so if it's correct as well it should be preferable.

Comment: Actually if I'm reading OP's comment correctly, my solution is correct and Gordon's isn't. If there's 2 rows that have equal a,b, which both have d='pi', they should both be included.

Comment: @popvitsj You are correct that yours works. Sorry, I hadn't checked it properly. The only place I'm not sure about the rules on is if there are two rows with equal a,b and neither have d='pi'. If the answer is to exclude them both then yours is correct. And for Gordon's to return both 'pi' rows he could use dense_rank() instead of row_number() to achieve that goal. My apologies,

Answer (score 1):

You can approach this with analytic functions, if you like:

```
select a, b, c, d
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by a, b
                                order by (case when d = 'pi' then 1 else 2 end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

use a where not exist construct:

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tab1
                  WHERE t.a = a AND t.b = b)
OR d ='pi'
```